# solving ODE: $\ln(y') + (x)y' -y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ODE
$$\ln(y') + (x)y' -y = 0$$

I can solve using power series, but it's not a very elegant approach. I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $y' \ne 0$.

Let's differentiate this equation once more:

$$\frac{y''}{y'}+xy''+y'-y'=\frac{y''}{y'}+xy''.$$
Suppose for the moment that $y''\ne0$, then we get $$1+xy'=0,$$
which gives $y(x) = Const -\ln |x|$. Let's put this expression to the initial equation:
$$\ln (-\frac 1x)-1-Const+\ln |x|=0.$$
Apparently, it has sense only for $x<0$ and implies $Const = -1$. So we have the first solution
$$y(x) = -1-\ln |x|,\quad x<0.$$

The second family of solutions comes from the option $y''=0$ or, in other words, $y(x)=ax+b$. We put it into the equation to obtain
$$\ln a+xa-xa-b=0$$or $a=e^b$; thus, the second solution has the form
$$y(x) = e^bx+b,\quad b\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I do have one questions though: is ln|x| differentiable? Otherwise y' will not be defined for this solution.

Comment: @InnocentRetard : you are welcome! Indeed, $\ln|x|$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you try $y=a x + b,$ you will be able to solve for $a$ and $b$ and be happy.

Comment: I'll be happier if you could give me some hints to get to the solution!

Comment: I just guessed (which is what you often have to do with ODEs.

Comment: @IgorRivin "often = always"

Comment: I agree with you, I need to develop such an intuition for ODEs myself.

Comment: Note that affine functions do not cover all possible solutions of this equation.

Comment: @user17762 I would say "often $\ne$ always".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is an example of a Clairaut equation, which is in the form $y=xy'+f(y')$ with $f(y')=\ln y'$ and the general solution will be all the sraight lines $y=cx+f(c)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. In your case, $f(c)=\ln c$, $c>0$, so $y=cx+\ln c$.

Comment: Note, however, that these straight lines do not represent `all` possible solutions.